# Cloying, but in a good way

Tags: single-word-requests

My wife was practicing a tune ("Rose Cottage") on her flute, and I was trying to think of a term to describe it.  "Cloying" came to mind, but, double-checking the definition, I see that it means not simply "sweet" and "sentimental", but sickeningly so.

**Is there a word which conveys the sense of being sweet and sentimental, perhaps approaching maudlin, but without the negative connotation of "cloying".**

If you want a tune to reference ("Rose Cottage" is hard to find on the web), think of the tune for "Danny Boy" (or, as I prefer to call it, "British Bottom").

**Update:**  I apologize for not clearly defining the sort of word I was looking for.  This is mainly because I sort of expected an obvious choice to pop out right away, either a common word I'd just overlooked, or an arcane musical term that is traditionally assigned to such music.  So I hadn't really thought through the criteria I'd use if no "obvious" term appeared.

The characteristics I hoped to capture were, best as I can express, these two:

1. A basic "heart-tugging" nature -- not so much in terms of calling up an emotion of sentimentality or passion or "tear jerking", but simply a sort of (alas, indescribable) flutter in your chest.  On hearing the tune you tend to stop and listen, and you feel this sort of need to take some deep breaths and let the music calm you.
2. (Speaking as a non-music person)  There seems to be something about the note progression that contributes to this "hear-tugging" effect.  The tunes are simple and, to my uneducated ear, completely lacking in any hint of dissonance.  But I suspect that it's more than that, that music theory (which includes the "rules" for note progressions) actually has a term for this.

It's worth noting that "A Gift to be Simple", one of the tunes I place in this category, has a much faster (and somewhat more irregular) tempo than the other two, so I don't think tempo is that much of a factor here.

Finally, I should reiterate that I'm speaking here of the TUNE, not any association that lyrics might have, nor any association with a particular instrument (though a flute has the advantage of producing a very "pure" note, avoiding harmonics which would complicate the note progression).

**The answer:**  I guess I must settle for "mesmerizing" as the word best fitting (albeit still poorly) my (admittedly poorly stated) criteria.  The suggestion of the Russian "toska" is maybe better, but it's pretty much unknown in English.

I'll give the bounty to Mari-Lou, though, since she had a lot of good input.

**Added:**  I was reminded today that Gustav Holst's [Thaxted](https://youtu.be/Udv7D50fg-w) has some of this same quality, even though it is of a much different style.

Comment: It might be charming, endearing, cute, or just plain sweet?

Comment: emotional, soulful ?

Comment: Perhaps _nostalgic_?

Comment: Is "Rose Cottage" a romantic uplifting tune, or a tear-jerker? *Danny Boy*, when sung well, can be incredibly touching.

Comment: Are you looking for a term that conveys a music's innocence and romantic charm, or its (stereotypical) sentimentality?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It's closer to "romantic and uplifting".  (Perhaps a better tune to reference is "A Gift to be Simple".  Something where the progression of notes has a magical quality.)

Comment: _dulcet_ or _idyllic_?

Comment: It is pretty hard when starting with a definition of *sickeningly sweet* to end up with a positive connotation.

Comment: A very good edit which came a bit late in the day, to say the least. There were plenty of occasions to make such a similar edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words that come to my mind are mesmerizing, emotive, poignant, melodic, inspirational, sublime, and ethereal.  There's something almost angelic about the way the song sounds, at least the flute version.

Comment: *poignant* is a good one, so +1, though I think it's used more often for stories and scenes and less often for music.   I suggest *moving* below.

Answer (score 13):

*[Wistful](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wistful)* comes to my mind when listening to various arrangements of *Rose Cottage*:

> full of yearning or desire tinged with melancholy;
>   also :  inspiring
>   such yearning
>
> <sub>*merriam-webster.com*</sub>

The *yearning and desire* would capture the ***sweet*** denotation in *[cloying](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloying)*, and the *tinge of melancholy* would capture the sense of ***maudlin***, while avoiding the derogatory *disgusting* or *excessive* connotations.

The comparison to *Danny Boy*, or more precisely the instrumental [*Londonderry Air*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gW7RBR6o78Q), seems quite appropriate. Both tunes have a similar [gaelic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_Gaelic_music) musical structure, which employs specific melodic phrasings with harmonic interaction to evoke the ***pensive melancholy*** of forlorn mourning in balance with the ***idyllic affection*** of fond musings. Experiencing these diametric sentiments in musical tandem connects us to the full emotional spectrum of our real-life passion and compassion.

Comment: Yes, that's getting closer.  I was kind of thinking that maybe there would be a semi-standard "suite" of terms for the "mood" of musical pieces, and it would be a simple matter to pick from that list, but I guess not.

Comment: @HotLicks, Don't you think the adjectives *wistful*, *maudlin*, *melancholic*  etc are not compatible with *soaring* and *uplifting*? They are more 'depressing' than 'uplifting'.

Comment: I'm not sure "sweet" is what I'd use for emotions of "yearning" and "desire" in a musical piece.  I think of "stirring" to describe music that moves me in that way, but that's me. :-)

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, @KristinaLopez. The entire set of *sweet*, *syrupy*, *saccharine*, etc. sits against the far wall of the OP's "emotional cottage", while *poignant* and *melancholy* sit against the opposite wall. Something has to stretch to reconcile *cloying* and *maudlin*! I like both *stirring* and *uplifting* as general descriptors. Of course, the major challenge of this question is the broad range of emotional experiences this song could produce among such a diverse community. It seems good to stack up all the reasonable options and let HotLicks make the final choice.

Comment: @KristinaLopez, I am not saying anything is right or wrong: the response to a tune is quite subjective. I am just pointing out that OP is contradicting himself: a tune can't be at the same time [**uplifting**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247194/cloying-but-in-a-good-way/249770#comment543552_249770)/ "soaring" and maudlin/ wistful, What is an [*uplifting song*](http://www.nme.com/photos/50-most-uplifting-songs-ever/279564#/photo/2) anyway? Must we find a synonym of "sweet-but-not-maudlin" (surely not "uplifting") or describe his *personal* emotional response (which is not mine) ?

Comment: Best choice yet. +1.

Comment: @KristinaLopez, I can't see how 'jinx' and 'riding a Harley' is relevant to my comment, which (*btw*) was not addressed to you. I was just pointing out that the thread has gone astray. The OP question asks for a word that means "sweet-but-not-too-sweet", what has "soaring/uplifting/moving/wistful/melancholic" etc. got to do with it? Everyone is describing the impression s/he gets from *Rose cottage*, what has that got to do with it, or with this site? Are we all musicologists, or what, when a tune can be defined 'uplifting'? Is it the notes or the arrangement or the tempo or the rendition?

Comment: @KristinaLopez,"*..you don't understand how music can be ascribed descriptive words..*" No , not again, the site and the question is about English, words and synonyms. OP changed the question in his comments, shifting the focus from the word 'cloying' to the impressions he/one gets from the tune. Just read the question with more care and see if you have answered that. I just reminded OP of the content of the question, I replied to you when you addressed me, and I do not wish to argue with you.

Comment: Me neither, @user77639.  I deleted all my comments to you! :-)

Comment: +1 especially for the reference to Gaelic music, which is a master genre at this particular feeling. For a few good examples, I'd suggest looking up _Cailín Deas Crúite na mBó_ or _Thíos Cois na Trá Domh_, both traditional Irish tunes filled to the brim with that ineffable, sweet, uplifting-yet-yearning something. (Both have lyrics, but I presume most here won't be distracted by their meaning, since they're in Irish.)

Answer (score 9):

The word *dulcet* might work. It has [one meaning](https://www.wordnik.com/words/dulcet) that is:

> Sweet, especially when describing voice or tones; melodious

Comment: Worth noting that dulcet is almost always used ironically or humorously.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction, I don't really agree with that. Can you support that statement?

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/dulcet

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction, I don't see how that link supports your opinion.

Comment: BrE /ˈdʌlsɪt/  ; NAmE /ˈdʌlsɪt/  (humorous or ironic)

Comment: _Dulcet_ is very commonly used ironically (the classic example, and probably the only context I’d really naturally use the word in normal conversation, being “Oh, I thought I recognised your dulcet tones”, said if you’ve just heard someone shouting their head off at someone else), but it can be used non-ironically, especially with music. “It was a dulcet little tune”, for example, bears no overtones of irony or humour, though it is fairly quaint.

Answer (score 6):

[Musical terms](http://www.musictheory.org.uk/res-musical-terms/italian-musical-terms.php) used in English.

- [dolce](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dolce)
- espressivo
- teneramente
- [affettuoso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Italian_musical_terms_used_in_English) (with feeling)
- grazioso

---

I might call a slightly sentimental and *romantic* song, *[charming](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/charming)* or *delightful*. And if a song  is described as being *[heart-warming](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heart-warming)*,  I doubt anyone would associate it with being overly-sweet or cutesy.

It's just come to me, the perfect word.

> **[mellifluous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mellifluous)**  (adjective)
>   1.
>   sweetly or smoothly flowing; sweet-sounding:
>   *a mellifluous voice*; *mellifluous tones*.

Some examples

> - *Mellifluous tunes capture Philemon and Baucis' good-heartedness.*
> - *Speaking from her Paris flat, 54 years on, Riva's voice is still as mellifluous and as gently mesmerising.*
> - As the first rain came down, Midlake brought a more sombre mood with a folk-rock set heavy on songs from The Courage of Others, **rich in mellifluous fluting** and intricate guitars

Finally, a list of the most appropriate suggestions.

- dolce
- affettuoso
- heartwarming
- mellifluous
- **mesmerising**

Answer (score 4):

*[Passion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passion)* might diminish the melancholy and describe the emotional experience more toward the sweetness:

> 4 a (1) :  emotion
>
> 5 a :  ardent affection :  love
>
> <sub>merriam-webster.com</sub>

With its rich heritage in the suffering of Jesus Christ, the connotation of sadness would still be present in the minds of many:

> 1 a :  the sufferings of Christ between the night of the Last Supper
> and his death
>
> <sub>merriam-webster.com</sub>

It also carries a hint of the special intimacy you and your wife enjoy:

> 5 c :  sexual desire
>
> <sub>merriam-webster.com</sub>

The word you use to modify passion can direct the attention exactly where you want it:

> My heart resonates with a **fond** passion when I listen to you play *Rose
> Cottage* on the flute.

Comment: Actually, "passionate" is sort of what I'm looking for.  Except that the term is rather cheapened by it's many associations, and it isn't very strongly associated with music.

Comment: Unfortunately, the musical association of *passion* tends toward sexual connotations, but I don't think *Rose Cottage* will throw you over that cliff ;-)

Comment: *Passion* does not conjure, using the OP's words: "sweet and sentimental", it doesn't have to be sexual either, but *passion* is nearly always emotional, and allows the interpreter to express great depth of feeling. Now, it seems to me that @HotLicks is no longer looking for a non-derogatory equivalent of *cloying*, but something that is closer to *inspirational*, perhaps more strongly related to *rapture* than sweetness and innocence. If you (hotlicks) have since changed your mind, you should edit your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[Twee](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/twee)
*adjective* 
1.
(Brit) excessively sentimental, sweet, or pretty

It's slangy, but it fits that meaning of being very sentimental, without necessarily going too far.

Comment: I've always heard twee used (lightly) pejoratively. As in, the woman wore a twee baby doll dress.

Comment: Maybe in transitioning to American usage it lost the pejorative. I've always heard it used for things that are very sweet, a bit affected, but not cloying.

Comment: that's funny, @Jason-M because I was thinking of its usage in US fashion magazines/blogs, so maybe the fashion industry has kept the light pejorative-- or maybe it just tends to critique everything so it just comes off as pejorative. Hmm...

Answer (score 3):

The tunes you mention are ***Moving***, in the sense that they affect emotions.

*Moving* does not have the negative connotations of *sappy*, *sentimental*, etc.

It can also cover cases of melodies that are uplifting as well as melancholy.

I no longer play an instrument, but I hearken back to various [Italian and English musical terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Italian_musical_terms_used_in_English#Moods) which underscored melodies like those you mention, and "with feeling" would seem to be the English instruction.    If the melody is *moving*, well, you play it with feeling. No negative connotations.  More specific terms might range from *Lacrimoso* to *Maestoso*, but they're all for *moving* tunes.

Answer (score 2):

When a sound is sweet, soft but pleasantly rich, full but delicate  : not harsh, bright, or irritating

the right word is (W,3):

[**mellow**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mellow#Adjective)

Answer (score 2):

Is [this](http://www.shazam.com/track/91318565/a-gaelic-offering-i-rose-cottage) the song you are referring to?

There's [a great site](http://composertools.com/Dictionary/MusicWords.htm#_Toc113338762) that explains a lot of terms you can use to talk about music.

In the "Musical Character" section there's a diagram, showing how certain words can be charted to understand musical descriptions. The one I would pick to describe the word you are looking for is 'delicate', 'whispery', or 'gentle'. I might have gone for 'fluid', too, but it's not fast enough in my mind.

Comment: The second video is the tune.  I suppose the first may be it too, but it gets lost in the orchestration.

Answer (score 2):

> My wife was practicing **a tune** ... on her flute, and I was
>   trying to think of a term to **describe it**. " ...
>   Is there a word which conveys the sense of being *sweet* and
>   *sentimental*, perhaps approaching *maudlin*,

I heve just realized that my previous post doesn't really address the question, (like all the other answers). You are asking to describe the tune but at the same time you seemed to describe the feelings that are evoked by the instrument: the flute. The sound, that is the [**timbre**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre) "...*of a musical instrument may be described with such words as bright, dark, warm, harsh, etc.*" and the sound of the flute is usually described described as 'not harsh', 'melodious', 'sweet' and its synonyms:  'mellow', mellifluos', 'dulcet':

> The American Standards Association definition 12.9 of timbre describes
>   it as "that attribute of sensation in terms of which a listener can
>   judge that two sounds having the same loudness and pitch are
>   dissimilar", adding, "Timbre depends primarily upon the spectrum of
>   the stimulus, but it also depends upon the waveform, the sound
>   pressure, the frequency location of the spectrum, and the temporal
>   characteristics of the stimulus"

Any tune played on a flute acquires a 'soothing', 'sweet', 'soft', 'tender, 'mellow' quality. You must consider also that both the arrangement and the tempo are adapted to the instrument.

You rightly compare ['*Rose cottage*'](https://youtu.be/NJoWGUucVEw?t=108) to  [**Danny Boy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Boy) since they are similar, but it is more appropriate to consider the latter, since we can't help thinking of the lyrics when we listen to the notes.

In the wiki article you can notice how the 'feeling' changes when the tune is played on a piano or sung by an [operatic contralto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Boy#Lyrics), you'll probably agree that there's nothing 'sweet', 'mellow', 'dulcet', 'cloying', 'maudlin' etc here

You can also compare your emotional response to the rendering by [Martin McCormack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAVNthnPieU), by [The Irish tenors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbEi5_w8Vzs&index=4&list=RD6ppdB6JX99Q) or by [Caitlin Heaney](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ppdB6JX99Q), and read one comment here saying : "*..it's probably the **saddest** song ever written"

Lastly, you can find a lot of interesting details on the song [here](http://www.standingstones.com/dannyboy.html) and may click on the link :"...I've now added a *MIDI version* of Bunting's arrangement, for people who would like to hear the original tune." , and listen to what is probably the most original version of the ballad.

Now, if you want to describe the *tune* (or the song) itself (and not the quality of the *instrument*), if you want to find a single word that cann best summarize its effect on the listener, i would suggest: "it's a *heart-clutching* tune"

Comment: I think perhaps an adjective you missed is "soaring".  The note progressions give one a sense of being lifted into the air.  I think it's that sense I've been trying to capture.

Comment: @HotLicks, you should specifty once and for all if you are referring to to tune or anything else, as I explained. Each element requires a different adjective and each particular rendition of the same element evokes a different feeling (and maybe defferent in each listener). There is nothing 'soaring' or 'sweet' in Bunting's arrangement, etc., you must have missed the point of my post.

Comment: I am speaking of the nature of the tune.  It is, of course, hard to separate it from the specific instrumentation (and, in the case of "Danny Boy" the lyrics), but I'm looking for a word for the intrinsic "hear tug" of the notes (which is, alas, largely absent in that Bunting piece).

Comment: @HotLicks, the notes  (with your 'intrinsic hear tug' ) are just 'moving' or as I said: *'heart-clutching'* or 'wrenching/-rending/ etc.." every instrument (flute, harp, guitar, piano etc.) adds its peculiar emotive touch/flavour/taste, and  every arrangement/ singer adds another unique 'tug' to the tune. You **cannot** possible find a word which is appropriate for all of them. The Bunting arrangement is the most true to a folk ballad, that should be your starting point. You might claim a sort of  'uplifting' effect in the Irish tenors' performance, but that is a long way from *The Derry Aire*

Comment: I've listened to the MIDI rendition of the popular score, and it is much different from the Bunting version.  My reference is the popular version.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is *saccharine*, although it too has some negative connotations:

> too sweet or sentimental; sweet or sentimental in a way that does not seem sincere or genuine

That's certainly the impression I get from hearing "Danny Boy."

Comment: That's getting closer.  But you're right -- it has a negative connotation.

Answer (score 1):

Although you've replaced "Danny Boy"/("British Bottom"?)/"The Londonderry Aire" with "A Gift to be Simple" as a tune of reference in a comment, I'll stubbornly stick with "Danny Boy," a [heartstring-tugging](http://www.bostonphoenix.com/supplements/the_best/98/text/AE_MCGANN_S.html) song. A real heartstring-tugger, borderline heart-clincher for sappy old me.

Answer (score 1):

I think of songs like "Danny Boy" and "Auld Lang Syne" as being full of ***"Sentimentality"***.  Combine the pleasing melody with the emotionally evocative lyrics and you end up with a song that stirs emotions and gains fans.   Throw in a bagpipe or two and you get a song that, like this version from "The High Kings" - ["The Parting Glass"](https://youtu.be/mUbNMxGdnCs) becomes a bona fide tear-jerker.

From [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentimentality):

> Sentimentality: 1:  the quality or state of being sentimental especially to excess or in affectation

While that seems to border on the negative, consider the examples, also from MW-O:

> 1: the sentimentality of Romantic poetry
>
> 2: the sentimentality of the story of star-crossed lovers only made it even more popular with moviegoers

Comment: I listened to that piece and only heard a hint of the attribute of which I speak.  Of course I was ignoring the lyrics -- just listening to the tune.

Comment: Right, and iconic tunes like Rose Cottage and Danny Boy don't even need the lyrics to produce the sentimentality because they're so well known and beloved.

Comment: Well, Rose Cottage, to my knowledge, does not have lyrics.  And it's not very well known at all.

Comment: ...and Danny Boy wouldn't necessarily be thought of so endearingly without the lyrics so maybe Danny Boy isn't the best comparison with Rose Cottage which is a contemporary composition that seems to be meant to have the sentimentality of old, well-known Gaelic melodies.

Comment: Sigh.  I guess most here are not hearing the same thing I'm hearing.

Comment: Seems so, @HotLicks.  May I ask...does it give you goosebumps or literally bring a tear to your eye?

Comment: Not that so much.  It's "uplifting".  Soothing, and seems to lighten the weight of the world a bit.  And I suspect that this has something to do with the tone progressions.  (Note: I know virtually nothing about music theory, so I'm just pulling that term out of the air.)  And there's something of an air of "perfection" to the sequence of notes, leaving one to feel that there maybe is some order in the Universe after all.

Comment: Gotcha...I will submit a new answer based on that very helpful description.

Comment: @HotLicks, "*Sigh. I guess most here are **not** hearing the same thing I'm hearing.*" Sure, I, for one, don't feel uplifted by *Rose cottage* nor do I think it is *sweet* or *moving*: actually, i think is a dull, uninspiring tune. The point I am making is that readers are supposed to find a word that fits a definition and **not** to try to interpret your emotional response, which you yourself seem unable to decipher.

Answer (score 1):

*"Is there a word which conveys the sense of being sweet and sentimental... but without the negative connotation of 'cloying'."*

I'm late to the party, but I nominate:

**[honeyed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/honeyed)**

> 1.1.  Rich and sweet in taste or smell:
>
> 2. *(Of a person’s words or tone of voice)* soothing, soft, and intended to please:
>
> *Jacques sighed, his anger melting away as her voice came across the line in honeyed tones...*

Cloyed is overly sweet, honeyed is sweet wothout negative connotations. It also has the figurative sense as required.

Also note the entry from [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/honeyed)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Pining**

*The mournful note of the pipes is sure to produce a pining for the Isles.*

One pines for something or someone one misses deeply and wishes to have or hold again.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudade#Similar_words_in_other_languages) describes pining as:

> "A nostalgic yearning for something that may no longer exist,
>   melancholic, fatalist overtone that the object of longing may never
>   return."

**Keening**

*The beauty of the song produced a deep keening in his heart.*

Keening, (etymology to cry or weep) is particularly Celtic, and perhaps therefore suited to a song like Danny Boy. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keening) describes it as:

> "...a form of vocal lament associated with mourning that is
>   traditional in Ireland, Scotland, and other cultures. In some cultures
>   it is customary for women to wail or keen at funerals."

Sometimes a loan word from a foreign language best captures the sense:

**Natsukashii**

The quality I believe you describe is particularly appreciated and treasured in Japan. *Natsukashii* is the word associated with it. It has connotations of reminiscence, homesickness and yearning. A gendre of Japanese music especially focused on this emotion is *enka* and is highly popular in karaoke bars. (The tears, the sake!)

**Toska**

The Russians also know this kind of sorrow and have a word for it: *Toska*. Nabokov described it:

> No single word in English renders all the shades of toska. At its
>   deepest and most painful, it is a sensation of great spiritual
>   anguish, often without any specific cause. At less morbid levels it is
>   a dull ache of the soul, a longing with nothing to long for, a sick
>   pining, a vague restlessness, mental throes, yearning. In particular
>   cases it may be the desire for somebody or something specific,
>   nostalgia, love-sickness. At the lowest level it grades into ennui,
>   boredom.

**Saudade**

In Portuguese, a sense of longing is conveyed by the word *saudade*.

Thank you for your beautiful question and lovely trip down memory lane.

Comment: "Toska" seems close, in a technical sense.  Alas, it lacks any emotive power in English.

Answer (score 1):

Is the word you seek, by any chance, a diminutive or compatriot of **perfervid** ?

> Perfervid : intense and impassioned.

I apologize for the lack of a more musical term.

Comment: That may be close, but is perhaps a bit too intense.   *Fervid* may be better.

Answer (score 0):

If asked to describe Danny Boy, I would use the word *melancholy*, as an adjective.